# SQL - returns a part of a field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split string in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql)

I have a column called `LastName` in the data base that has the following value:

```
Johnson  (Ext. 12345)
```

I only want to return the Last name without the extension.

Any idea what command to use in T-SQL? (for SSRS 2008 version)

thanks

Comment: Does the lastname always have a space before an open bracket?

Comment: yes, it always have a space

Answer (score 2):

give this a try,

```
SELECT RTRIM(SUBSTRING(LastName, 1, CHARINDEX('(', LAstName) - 1)) LastName
FROM table1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/176db/3)

Answer (score 1):

You can;

```
left(fld, charindex(' ', fld + ' ', 1) - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

First allow me to say that such composite values in a single field are against normalization, present various problems regarding the integrity, duplication etc of data and also present problems on simple queries as the one you are trying to perform.

If you can you should split Last name and Ext in two different columns.

For answers to you question check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-reco)

Comment: Yes but naming conventions vary across cultures.  Some people have four, five six or more names: how many columns is enough?

Comment: well in the case that you do not know the number of columns to associate, you can take a different approach, you can keep such values as rows of a different table, and relate to them via a foreign key, where one row on the main table can be associated to many rows on the secondary table. But this is just one approach, depending on the domain there can be various solutions.